# How to change Time.deltaTime value?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection

Is there any way to change Unity's Time.deltaTime value with reflection or with some other method.
We have a replay system which we use mainly for bug hunting.
It stores all the input events and delta time values than we can simulate the game exactly the same . But to force delta time values we have to define and use a custom deltaTime variable. I want to get rid of that variable and also force unity's systems to use our value.

```
class SystemManager
{
     List<System> systems;
     void Update()
     {
          if(replay)
          {
               DTime.deltaTime = deltaTimeBuffer.GetValue();
          }else
          {
               DTime.deltaTime = Time.deltaTime;
          }

          foreach system in systems
               system.Update();

     }
}


class System
{
     void Update()
     {
          position += DTime.deltaTime * velocity;
          // I want to get rid of DTime.deltaTime and use Time.deltaTime
     }
}
```

Comment: hmmm .. use your custom variable ^^ .. you could have a central controller for it `public float deltaTime => replay ? simulatedDeltaTime : Time.deltaTime;`

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this one https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection to change platform-wide known variable might lead to some weird bugs once for example "new developer" in team will not know about that feature and will have to know why his deltaTime is not what he expects to be.

Regardless of that digression - maybe not exactly changing deltaTime directly but You could change your target frame rate.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-targetFrameRate.html

As delta time is just:

> The interval in seconds from the last frame to the current one (Read Only).

Source: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html

By calculating new target frame rate (if Your machine will be able to stably work on that frame rate) You could possibly get deltaTime that You want.